# Signs of minors of a real matrix with negative diagonal entries, positive off-diagonal entries, and negative row sums

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix where the diagonal entries are negative, the off-diagonal entries are positive, the row sums are negative, and sign$(|A|)=(-1)^n$.  Let $M$ be the $i,j$ minor of $A$.  My numerical examples suggest that
$$\frac{|M|}{|A|}(-1)^{i+j}<0$$
for all $i,j$, but I cannot find a way to prove it.  Any suggestions for how to prove it or for a counterexample?

Comment: What is $J$...?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $A$.  I've corrected the inequality.

Comment: The conditions imply that $-A$ is strictly diagonal-dominant. Your claim asserts that $A^{-1}$ has only negative entries (use adjoint matrix). This seems unlikely to hold in general.